# Session management without using webView

Tags: android, android-layout

I need to implement session for my android application after a user has successfully logs into application. But i want this by using application not webView. And this login credentials is sent to server for authentication. Can it we possible without using webView.

Answer (score 1):

For this u can use preference.if The login is sucessful u can set the username and password in prefernce.if user loged out preference sets back to the defult guest account.

refer this..http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/Preference.html

if the login is suceesful set preference like this

```
 String user_name_key = "Username";
String pass_word_key = "Password";

String Shared_preference_key = "Shared Preference";
private SharedPreferences USERNAME_and_PASSWORD;





public boolean setUserName(String userName) {
    editor = USERNAME_and_PASSWORD.edit();
    editor.putString(user_name_key, userName);
    editor.commit();
    return true;
}

public boolean setPassword(String password) {

    editor = USERNAME_and_PASSWORD.edit();
    editor.putString(pass_word_key, password);
    editor.commit();
    return true;
}
```

Comment: can you kindly elaborate or refer one example.

Comment: can this SharedPreference be used by android service even if user is not active or not logged in?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the SharedPreferences  for this to storing the info of the logged in user .

```
// Access the default SharedPreferences
  SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE).edit();


// Edit the saved preferences
editor.putString("UserName", "JaneDoe");
editor.putInt("password", "******");
editor.commit();
```

and these value can be retrieve in this way .

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE); 
String UserName= prefs.getString("UserName", null);
```

So that this info can be used in application everywhere .

Comment: can this SharedPreference be used by android service even if user is not active or not logged in?

Comment: This will depends on mode of the sharedPreferences  . but i am not fully sure about this . but if we declare mode to public then may be services can access the data .

Comment: but for this you can also use the Content provider . this will definitely solve your problem  .